# Area between parabola and two tangent lines of parabola

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be the region enclosed by parabola $y=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}-2x+2$ and tangent lines of parabola at $(1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(4,2)$. Find the area of $R$.

I know the formula of tangent line of parabola $(x-a)^{2}=4p(y-b)$ is
$$(y-b)=m(x-a)-pm^{2}$$.

But I have no idea how to combine the tangent lines with the parabola into an equation to be integrated.

I have next question with multiple points of tangent line of parabola, so is there any guide to solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote

$$ f(x)\equiv \frac{1}{2}x^{2}-2x+2, \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\; f'(x) \equiv x-2$$

The first tangent line, $t_1(x)$, goes through $(1,1/2)$ and has slope $f'(1)=-1$, so:

$$ t_1(x) = \frac{3}{2}-x.$$

The second tangent line, $t_2(x)$, goes through $(4,2)$ and has slope $f'(4)=2$, so:

$$ t_2(x) = -6+2x.$$

The two tangents intersect at

$$ \frac{3}{2}-x = -6+2x \Rightarrow x = \frac{5}{2}. $$

Hence, the integral you are looking for is:

$$ \int_1^{\frac{5}{2}} f(x)-t_1(x)dx + \int_{\frac{5}{2}}^4 f(x)-t_2(x)dx. $$

Comment: Thanks! If I have three points, then I need to solve the $x$ for three linear equations together or is there another way to do around it?

Comment: Then, you will have 3 tangent lines. You are going to have to find two intersection points: where the first one intersect the second, and where the second intersects the third. Where the first is the one with the lowest $x$ coordinate and so on. Try drawing the curve and the tangents to understand why.

Comment: So there would be still two integrals, right?

Comment: No, in that case there would be three.

Comment: I get it :-). Let's say I have three points are distributed along the parabola line, so there will be three integrals, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Find the equation of the two tangent lines, call them $y_1$ and $y_2$.
Find the intersection of $y_1$ and $y_2$, call it $(x_c, y_c)$. Break the interval out and integrate: $$ \int_1^{x_c} (y - y_1) dx + \int_{x_c}^4 (y - y_2) dx $$
To understand this better, make a sketch of the problem.